# Saving files from multiple file uploads in Asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, file-upload, entity-framework-6

So I have a view that has around 6 file upload controls. Note that the view has other controls are well. Upon submit, I need to create a folder and save the submitted files into that folder and then save the entity to the database.

Question : What is the best approach to map the saved file paths to the respective properties of the model? I am able to do it using switch case, but I do not like they way I am doing it. Note that not all files are mandatory?

Sample Code:

```
int index = 0;
foreach (var file in files)
{
    if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);

        var path = Path.Combine(dpath, fileName);
        file.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(path));
        switch (index)
        {
            case 0:
                t.file1 = path;
                break;
            case 1:
                t.file2 = path;
                break;
            case 2:
                t.file3 = path;
                break;
            case 3:
                t.file4 = path;
                break;
            case 4:
                t.file5 = path;
                break;
            case 5:
                t.file6 = path;
                break;
        }
    }
    index++;
}
```

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: What's the question here? *best approach* there is no best approach

Comment: What is the best approach to map the saved file paths to the respective properties of the model? I am able to do it using switch case, but I do not like they way I am doing it.

Comment: What I mean is there any better alternative than using switch?

Comment: why, that just seems like a waste of time and effort

Comment: Problem with this approach is the assumption that the file upload controls are in a fixed order. If the order of the fileupload controls in the view change, the switch case also needs to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the best approach and the order of the `fileUpload` controls in the view page, are dependent on `t.file` (model). It's just another option:

```
public virtual ActionResult UploaderAction(SomeViewModel t, HttpPostedFileBase [] uploadedFile)
{ 
    for(int i = 0; i < uploadedFile.length; i++)
    {
        if (uploadedFile[i] != null && uploadedFile[i].ContentLength > 0)
        {
            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(uploadedFile[i].FileName);

            var path = Path.Combine(dpath, fileName);
            uploadedFile[i].SaveAs(Server.MapPath(path));

            t.file[i] = path;
        }
    }
}
```